# Firebase data retrieval : I am not able to retrieve data from the json created in the Firebase database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my data base structure

```
{
  "main" : {
    "fake data1" : {
      "abc" : "1001",
      "high" : "100",
      "low" : "150",
      "mid" : "200",
      "name" : "fake data1"
    },
    "fake data2" : {
      "abc" : "1023",
      "high" : "1020",
      "low" : "1020",
      "mid" : "1501",
      "name" : "fake data2"
    },
    "fake data3" : {
      "abc" : "1001",
      "high" : "100",
      "low" : "150",
      "mid" : "200",
      "name" : "fake data3"
    },
    "fake data4" : {
      "abc" : "1023",
      "high" : "1020",
      "low" : "1020",
      "mid" : "1501",
      "name" : "fake data4"
    },
    "fake data5" : {
      "abc" : "1001",
      "high" : "100",
      "low" : "150",
      "mid" : "200",
      "name" : "fake data5"
    },
    "fake data6" : {
      "abc" : "1023",
      "high" : "1020",
      "low" : "1020",
      "mid" : "1501",
      "name" : "fake data6"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve all names from the above, but I am not able to do it.

I am trying with the following query:

```
   var datafire = firebase.database().ref();
   var namedb = datafire.child('main')
   var query = namedb.orderByChild('name')
   query.on("value", function(datasnap) {
                        var data = (datasnap.val());
                        console.log(data.name);
```

Comment: I think you are missing `fake data1` , `fake data2` in your query

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code will need to handle the fact that the snapshot contains multiple items by using `Snapshot.forEach()` to loop over these items:

```
var datafire =firebase.database().ref();
var namedb = datafire.child('main')
var query = namedb.orderByChild('name')
query.on("value",function(datasnap){
  datasnap.forEach(function(child) {
    var data=child.val();
    console.log(child.key, data.name);
  });
});
```